# How to seperate added objects

Tags: mesh, objects, sculpting

I'm trying to create a mesh for a head and I got to the part where I needed to add spheres for the eyes. So I added one but it's become part of the rest of the head if that makes sense so I can't move or edit just the sphere. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Z</kbd> doesn't go back far enough to undo it, is it possible to separate them?

[image]

Comment: It sounds as if you added it while you were in Edit mode instead of Object mode which means it's part of the main head mesh. Select All ('A' key) in Edit mode, then hit 'P' > Seperate > By Loose Parts. When you go back into Object mode you'll then have two seperate objects.

Comment: @JohnEason Might work in this case, but as a general method it would be better to use P and only separate selected vertices (like the accepted answer). If one added some mesh accidentally in _Edit Mode_ to an object which already consists of lots of loose parts, separating by loose parts could be very annoying.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann True, but in this case it was pretty obvious that there would only be two objects from the supplied image.

Comment: @JohnEason Of course you're right, that's all fine. I was just thinking of one of the goals of this site to also provide useful information for future users where it might be not so obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to *Edit Mode* (<kbd>Tab</kbd>), select the sphere's vertices, hit <kbd>P</kbd> > *Selection* in the menu. This should make the sphere a separate object.

Comment: @user160767 As an addition, to select only the sphere's vertices without having to manually select them and beware you don't select vertices from the rest of the mesh: make sure to deselect all with Alt+A, then hover the mouse over the sphere and press L to select all vertices connected to the sphere and none of the others.