# When I create a new object it will automatically connect to another if they are close enough. How do I fix this?

Tags: mesh, materials

When I create, via <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or copy and paste, an object it will merge with the other, their meshes will be separate and they often aren't physically connecting, yet it seems impossible to separate them. How do I unpair them?

Comment: maybe you are still in Edit mode, or you need to disable the Proportional Editing option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to seperate added objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283588/how-to-seperate-added-objects)

Comment: As @moonboots says, you've added or copied and pasted in Edit mode so it's still a single object. Add or copy them in Object mode and you'll have seperate objects.